# What does the period mean when used with ~ (in a formula)?

Tags: r, statistics

From the [FSelector manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf):

```
data(iris)
subset <- cfs(Species~., iris)
f <- as.simple.formula(subset, "Species")
print(f)
```

Specifically, I mean the one in "Species~.".

Now, it's awfully tough to Google how a bit of punctuation is used (for me anyway) and I couldn't anything. This code is unclear.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dot-in-r

Comment: @gsk3 I think a duplicates should come from SO.

Comment: @Roman fair 'nuff, although that CV question probably belongs on SO since it has nothing to do with stats :-)

Comment: @gsk3 I think this one's in the gray zone. X-)

Answer (score 21):

I think you're referring to the period contained in `Species~.`, in which case this is just the standard R formulation of referring to 'all other variables' in the data frame, rather than typing them out one by one, as in `Species ~ Variable1 + Variable2` etc.

From the help files of `?formula`:

> There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one
>   is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and
>   means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see terms.formula.
>   In the context of update.formula, only, it means ‘what was previously
>   in this part of the formula’.

Comment: @Kristoff - I wrote that and then went to look up where to read about it...answer edited now.

Comment: @Kristoff, if you found this answer to be useful and is what you were looking for, consider accepting it as the correct answer (the little gray tick that turns green when you click on it).