# What is the meaning of . in aggregate function?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the period mean in the following R excerpt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951090/what-does-the-period-mean-in-the-following-r-excerpt)

in the aggregate help file:

```
Dot notation:  
aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris, mean)  
aggregate(len ~ ., data = ToothGrowth, mean)
```

What is meaning of `.`  here?

Answer (score 7):

It means "all other variables."  That is, those variables of the data which are not otherwise present in the formula.

In the first expression, these are `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width` as can be seen by running the command:

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris, mean)  
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

This statement is equivalent:

```
aggregate(cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, data = iris, mean)
```

Comment: Note though that the use of cbind requires all arguments to be of the same type, so you couldn't do (for example) `aggregate(len ~ cbind(supp,dose),data=ToothGrowth,mean)` - you have to do `aggregate(len ~ .,data=ToothGrowth,mean)` or `aggregate(len ~ supp+dose,data=ToothGrowth,mean)`

Answer (score 6):

From [`?formula`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html)

> There are two special interpretations of ‘.’ in a formula.  The
>        usual one is in the context of a ‘data’ argument of model fitting
>        functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’:
>        see ‘terms.formula’.  In the context of ‘update.formula’, *only*,
>        it means ‘what was previously in this part of the formula’.