# How to automatically create columns for many empty dataframes without losing the data of those that are not empty in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, function

I have more than 100 excels in a file that I imported using the following code inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47540572/11584327).

```
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
for(i in file.list) {
  assign(sub(".xlsx", "", i), read_excel(i))
}
```

Most of them are empty, thus without rows nor columns in the Global environment (tbl_df type of length 0 with 0 observations of 0 variables).
For all these imported objects, I would like to create 5 columns named "A", "B", "C", "D", "E".
The following code works well:

```
files_list <- ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)
for(df in files_list)
  assign(df, setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 0)), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))
```

However, among all the initial objects, few have already head columns and rows with values (i.e., their original excels had 5 columns and included data); unfortunately, the code above overwrites the values of these excels which therefore disappear ("No data available in table").
My future goal being to merge rows from all these excels without losing the few pre-existing data, how can I create 5 columns for all the empty dataframes while keeping the data from the non-empty ones?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please be more specific in your desired outcome, adding columns to every empty file with zero rows makes no sense. Zero rows remain zero rows, and to me it looks like you want to merge all files with data and then make sure columns A-E are present as well.  You can handle that after the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `assign` is generally considerd [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-from-r-to-excel).

My solution to your problem would be to write a function to read a single excel file, check to see if it has zero rows and create the replacement data frame if it does, and then to use `lapply` to call this function on your file list.  `lapply` returns a `list`, which should be easier to use downstream than a series of standalone objects.

```
library(readxl)

myData <- lapply(
  list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE),
  function(f) {
    d <- read_excel(f)
    if (nrow(d) == 0) {
      d <- data.frame(A = NA, B = NA, C = NA, D = NA, E = NA)
    }
    d
  }
)
```

If you need to know which data frame is associated with which file, you can then, for example, do

```
names(myData) <- sub(".xlsx", "", list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx"))
```

This is untested code because your example is not reproducible.

Comment: Columns are created with the appropriate headers A to E for the empty dataframes, but columns headers from the non-empty dataframes are not renamed (they keep headers from the original excels). However, it is not a problem since I can list2env(myData, envir=.GlobalEnv) then rename headers form all dataframes using e.g., z0 <- ls(envir=.GlobalEnv); for(z1 in z0) assign(z1, setNames(get(z1),  c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))). So thank you very much.

Comment: There are other, simpler, safer, better ways to rename the columns in data frames with data.  *Please, please* don't use `list2env`.  IMHO, your original question did not make it clear that you wanted to rename the columns in *all* the imported data frames, including those with data.  This is yet another reason why a minimal, reproducible example, including test input and expected output is *always* helpful.