# Object 'true' not found

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
unlink(dir, recursive = true)
```

And I am getting this error message:

```
* object 'true' not found
```

What is the cause of the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean constants are in all caps - use TRUE/FALSE. Other languages usually define them as true/false. So the correct code would be:

```
unlink(dir, recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: dot has a meaning, for example see: [`.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457), see also [`...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions)

Comment: @Honza While the first part of your reply is the correct answer, the second part is wrong, as previous poster pointed out. `.` can actually have many meanings and purposes. On a side note: you can abbreviate `TRUE` to `T` and `FALSE` to `F`.

Comment: @SachaViquerat If you abbreviate then take care: never write something like `T <- 0` or `F <- 1` in your code!

Comment: @jogo - so true! That's what `d`, `x` and `s` are for :)