# What does the magrittr dot/period (".") operator do when it's at the very beginning of a pipeline?

Tags: r, ggplot2, magrittr

I don't understand what the `.` in the following code is doing or where to find documentation for it:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width), 
    data = . %>% filter(Species == 'setosa')
  )
```

This appears to be behaving quite differently from the usage described in [What does the dplyr period character "." reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457/what-does-the-dplyr-period-character-reference) where the `.` does not appear in the left-hand-most position.

The docs [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) say merely

> A pipeline with a dot (.) as LHS will create a unary function. This is
>   used to define the aggregator function.

but this is not at all clear to me and I'm hoping for more information.

Comment: It's the previous data.frame.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be or where the documentation is?

Comment: Documentation? Here we go: [magrittr v1.5](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/magrittr/versions/1.5), [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html). Cheers

Comment: The only explanation in those docs is "A pipeline with a dot (.) as LHS will create a unary function. This is used to define the aggregator function." ... i was hoping for MORE information by asking this question...

Comment: it seems like it means that it will act like `function(x) {x}` is that right?

Comment: By `identity` and `identity()` do not work in this place. Not worthy of its own question/answer here? certainly neither of the linked "dupes" elucidate this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion here can actually come from two places.

First, yes, the `. %>% something()` syntax creates a "unary" function that takes one argument. So:

```
. %>% filter(Species == 'setosa')
```

is equivalent to

```
function(.) filter(., Species == 'setosa')
```

The second part here is that `ggplot2` layers can actually take a function as their `data` argument. From e.g. `?geom_point`:

> *The data to be displayed in this layer. There are three options:*
>
> ...
>
> *A function will be called with a single argument, the plot data. The return value must be a data.frame, and will be used as the layer data.*

So the function that is passed to `geom_point` will always be applied to the default plot data (i.e. the data defined in `ggplot()`).

Note that your linked question concerns the use of `.` in `funs()`, which is not directly related to it's use here.

Comment: Thanks! So is it fair to say that the `.` by itself is equivalent to `function(x){x}` in this context?

Comment: `.` by itself does nothing, it's the `%>%` that recognizes it and does all the magic. So you really `. %>% something` as a combination for a function to be created. You can look at the source of the pipe and see it explicitly checks if the left hand side (LHS) is a placeholder (i.e. `.`), so it is programmed as a special case.