# How is the data argument passed through ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm trying to include subsets directly in the `geom` argument in ggplot, and am trying to understand what seems to be inconsistent behavior.

If I use `data = . %>% filter()` it works, but if I try to use `data = filter(.)` I get an error message. Outside of a ggplot flow those two syntaxes are normally interchangeable, so what's going on here?

```
library(tidyverse)

# piping in, works
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(speed > 10))

# '.' in function, error: "object '.' not found"
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_point(data = filter(. , speed > 10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I understand what's going on under the hood.

Generally and according to `magrittr` syntax

```
. %>% some_function(...)
```

is short for

```
function(x) some_function(x, ...)
```

So in your case,

```
. %>% filter(speed > 10)
```

can be expanded to

```
function(x) filter(x, speed > 10)
```

We can confirm that indeed

```
ggplot(data = cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point(data = function(x) filter(x, speed > 10))
```

works and gives the same results as for your "piping in, work" example.

So they key here is to recognise that `data` (inside `geom_point`) can take a *function* as an argument. The function is an anonymous function that is applied to the `data` argument from your main `ggplot2` call.

To quote from [`ggplot2` issue #1486](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/1486)

> This PR will make it possible to supply a function as the data argument to the layer function. The function will be applied to the global data of the plot and the result will be used in the layer.

With all of this in mind it then becomes clear why

```
... + geom_point(data = filter(. , speed > 10))
```

doesn't work. `data` in `geom_*` needs to be either a `data.frame` or a function returning a `data.frame` that is applied to the `data` argument of the main `ggplot2` call.

Comment: But isn't `.` or even `filter(. , speed > 10)` a data.frame here ?

Comment: No I don't think so. `. %>% filter(speed > 10)` is short for an anonymous function; that's `magrittr` syntax, see e.g. [What does the magrittr dot/period (“.”) operator do when it's at the very beginning of a pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436488/what-does-the-magrittr-dot-period-operator-do-when-its-at-the-very-beginn);`ggplot2` itself doesn't know anything about `.` (as the error indicates).