# Why do you have to use "." when combining dplyr with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

When i use ggplot without dplyr I can simply write something along the lines of:

```
ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=FLYTT))+geom_bar()+coord_flip()
```

The intuitive way of combining dplyr with ggplot for me would be to write:

```
fulldata%>%ggplot(,aes(x=FLYTT))+geom_bar()+coord_flip()
```

Since according to the logic in dplyr, the data argument should not have to be explicitly stated.

When I write this, however, the program throws an error since it can't find the missing x aesthetic.

To rectify this, I have to write:

```
fulldata%>%ggplot(.,aes(x=FLYTT))+geom_bar()+coord_flip()
```

What does the "." mean in this context and why won't the code work without it?

Comment: Remove comma, it should work fine. `mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = cyl)) + geom_bar()`

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea of what the period means though? I'm trying to get a better understanding of the syntax.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457/what-does-the-dplyr-period-character-reference) for dot meaning. (Possible duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to use `.`, just like this

`fulldata %>% ggplot(aes(x=FLYTT))+geom_bar()+coord_flip()`