# Duplicate first occurence of string into column of data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe

In a data frame, I am attempting to duplicate the first occurence of a string into the same column, but also into the neighbouring column. More specifically, I want the first occurence of a string in column v1 to be duplicated and inserted above itself and above the same row in column v2, as exemplified in the mock data frame below:

Input:

```
df_1<-data.frame("v1"=c(rep("a",times=3),rep("aa",times=4)),"v2"=c(c("b","c","d"),c("bb","cc","dd","ee")))
df_1
      v1 v2
    1  a  b
    2  a  c
    3  a  d
    4 aa bb
    5 aa cc
    6 aa dd
    7 aa ee
```

Expected output:

```
df_2<-data.frame("v1"=c(rep("a",times=4),rep("aa",times=5)),"v2"=c(c("a","b","c","d"),c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee")))
df_2
    v1 v2
    1  a  a
    2  a  b
    3  a  c
    4  a  d
    5 aa aa
    6 aa bb
    7 aa cc
    8 aa dd
    9 aa ee
```

So in this case, the first occurence of "a" and "aa" has been duplicated and inserted into the same data frame above it's first occurence.

I hope my question makes sense.

Best,
Rikki

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R idea:

```
 do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df_1, df_1$v1), function(i)
                                 rbind(data.frame(v1 = i$v1[1], v2 = i$v1[1]), i)))
#     v1 v2
#a.1   a  a
#a.2   a  b
#a.3   a  c
#a.4   a  d
#aa.1 aa aa
#aa.4 aa bb
#aa.5 aa cc
#aa.6 aa dd
#aa.7 aa ee
```

**NOTE:** You can use `rownames() <- NULL` to remove the rownames If they bother you.

**EDIT**
Apparently there is a `make.row.names` arguments in the `data.frame`-method of `rbind` as provided in comments by @Jaap:

```
do.call(rbind, c(lapply(split(df_1, df_1$v1),
                        function(i) rbind(data.frame(v1 = i$v1[1], v2 = i$v1[1]), i)),
                 make.row.names = FALSE)
        )
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, c(lapply(split(df_1, df_1$v1), function(i) rbind(data.frame(v1 = i$v1[1], v2 = i$v1[1]), i)), make.row.names = FALSE))`

Comment: Sotos and Jaap, thank you so much for this compact solution.

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df_1 %>%
 group_by(v1) %>%
 uncount((row_number() == 1) + 1) %>%
 mutate(v2 = if_else(row_number() == 1, first(v1), v2))

  v1    v2   
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     a    
2 a     b    
3 a     c    
4 a     d    
5 aa    aa   
6 aa    bb   
7 aa    cc   
8 aa    dd   
9 aa    ee
```

Comment: Thanks a lot tmfmnk. I haven't familiarized myself with dplyr yet, but I will do my best to get to my head around this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rep` to copy the matching rows and then overwrite *v2*:

```
i <- !duplicated(df_1$v1)
df_2 <- df_1[rep(seq_len(length(i)), 1+i),]
i <- which(i)
i <- i + seq(0, length.out=length(i))
df_2$v2[i] <- df_2$v1[i]
#df_2[i,] <- df_2$v1[i]   #Alternative
#df_2[i,-1] <- df_2$v1[i] #Alternative
df_2
#    v1 v2
#1    a  a
#1.1  a  b
#2    a  c
#3    a  d
#4   aa aa
#4.1 aa bb
#5   aa cc
#6   aa dd
#7   aa ee
```

Comment: GKi, thank you so much for the solution. I have to admit it's quite advanced for me, but I will take it bit by bit :).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr) 

df_1 %>% 
  select(v1) %>% 
  mutate(v2 = v1) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  rbind(df_1) %>% 
  arrange(v1)
```

Which gives:

```
  v1 v2
1   a  a
11  a  b
2   a  c
3   a  d
4  aa aa
41 aa bb
5  aa cc
6  aa dd
7  aa ee
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. Even without familiarity with dplyr, this seems very logical. Just one thing: the punctiation (.) in rbind(.,) calls the result from the unique() function, right?

Comment: After you asked this, I re-ran the code above without the dot, and it turns out you don't actually need it. It is used to pass the transformed data from the left hand side to the right hand side (you can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457/what-does-the-dplyr-period-character-reference#:~:text=The%20dot%20is%20used%20within,reference%20single%20columns%20by%20using%20.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Matt.