# How does this anonymous function syntax work?

Tags: r

I am self-studying R.  Below is a silly question:

```
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x))
```

I understand everything except the '.x'.  What does it means?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the dplyr period character "." reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457/what-does-the-dplyr-period-character-reference)

Comment: @mhovd No, that’s a different, unrelated usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.x` refers to the dataframe in each list.

```
tmp <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)
```

So for 1st iteration `.x` would be `tmp[[1]]`, for second `tmp[[2]]` and so on. Note that instead of `.x` you can also use `.` here which would return the same output.

See documentation in `?map` :

```
There are three ways to refer to the arguments:

For a single argument function, use .

For a two argument function, use .x and .y

For more arguments, use ..1, ..2, ..3 etc
```