# How to pass a data in a pipe to colSums

Tags: r

I would like to use  `%>%` to pass a data through `colSums`. In fact, this should apply to all the calculations.

Here is my example:

I can use following codes to reach my goal:

```
result<- colSums(!is.na(df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

how can I rewrite my codes to sth that looks like this:

```
result <- df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")] %>%
colSums(!is.na(), na.rm = TRUE)
```

These codes did not work. And I got error codes `Error in is.na() : 0 arguments passed to 'is.na' which requires 1`. Could anyone  give me some guidance?

Thanks

Update:

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(A = c("A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, 
NA, "B", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), C = c(NA, "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), D = c(NA, NA, NA, "D", "D", NA, NA, NA), RT = c(NA, 
"RT", NA, NA, NA, NA, "RT", NA), PR = c(NA, NA, "PR", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), OTH = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "OTH", NA, NA, "OTH")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You already have an answer, but for more general cases, these posts may be useful: [Using the %>% pipe, and dot (.) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation), [What does the dplyr period character “.” reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457/what-does-the-dplyr-period-character-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the pipe does is put what comes before the pipe as the first argument of what comes after, so

```
# What the pipe does
## with pipe
x %>% foo(other_arg)
## equivalent to this:
foo(x, other_arg)

## your version piped:
df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")] %>%
  colSums(!is.na(), na.rm = TRUE)

## is interpreted like this:
colSums(df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")], !is.na(), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Hopefully the above makes sense, and you can see why you get an error about `is.na()` needing an argument.

You can use the pipe, but as you note the `!` takes special handling. `!` as a prefix has higher precedence than `%>%`, so R will try to evaluate the `!` result *before* piping into it. To work around this, we can call `!` explicitly as a function, rather than a prefix operator. Alternately, if you load the `magrittr` package (the original source of `%>%`), it provides aliases for cases like this, including the `not()` function which is an alias for `!`. These are demonstrated below:

```
df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")] %>%
  is.na() %>%
  `!`() %>%
  colSums(na.rm = TRUE)

library(magrittr)
df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")] %>%
  is.na() %>%
  not() %>%
  colSums(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: The last one works. I thought `colSums(!is.na(.), na.rm = TRUE)` should work. however it did not.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. I'll have to investigate more...

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my code in the following way. I don't know why when I negate `is.na` I just can't get the desired result with a pipe

```
colSums(!is.na(df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")]))

  A   B   C   D  RT  PR OTH 
  1   1   1   2   2   1   2
```

Only in this way you can count those values which are not `NA`. If you want to stick to base R.

Comment: Just bear in mind that when you pass a data into another function, the first argument of that function should be a data frame or a vector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I used `!is.na()` is count the number of cases with answer for `a,b,c ,d, etc`. They are character variables instead of numbers. Any way I can keep `!is.na()`?

Comment: Your welcome. Not in the `colSums` but you can use it in your result vector.

Comment: I just updated the post with sample data. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my code. It's a kind of weird case with `is.na` we can use pipe but if I negate it the result would not be the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

dplyr style would be

```
result <- df[ , c("A", "B", "C","D", "RT", "PR", "OTH")] %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~colSums(!is.na(.), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: I got error codes` Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
i Input `..1` is `across(everything(), ~colSums(!is.na(.), na.rm = TRUE))`.`