# The meaning of Dot in summarise function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

I followed this code to create the row total for the dataframe `df`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(., across(where(is.numeric), sum),
                                across(where(is.character), ~'Total')))
```

If I modified the code, it would return an error

```
df <- df %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum),
                             across(where(is.character), ~'Total')))

# Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

My question is: what does the dot `.` inside the `summarise` refer to? Why was it needed for the code to run properly? My guess was that the dot referred to the dataframe `df`, which was already implied by the part `df %>%`. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dot-in-r#:%7E:text=It%20is%20just%20a%20variable,of%20alphanumerics%20and%20dot%20(.)) didn't answer my question.

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457/what-does-the-dplyr-period-character-reference) is relevant.

Comment: It’s hard to imagine that this has not been asked and answered before. The first thing I would try is search on “[tidyverse] meaning of dot”

Comment: Thanks @benson23 for the answer. I now realised that I should have included the specific term `dplyr` in my google search to find relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In magrittr, `.` represents the object on the left-hand side (lhs) of the pipe. By default, the lhs is passed to the first argument of the function on the rhs. But if you want to also use the lhs elsewhere in the rhs, you can use `.`.

In your examples,

```
df %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), sum),
    across(where(is.character), ~'Total')
  ))
```

is equivalent to

```
bind_rows(
  df,
  summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), sum),
    across(where(is.character), ~'Total')
  )
)
```

This throws an error because `summarise()` expects a dataframe as its first argument. Whereas

```
df %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(
    .,
    across(where(is.numeric), sum),
    across(where(is.character), ~'Total')
  ))
```

is equivalent to

```
bind_rows(
  df,
  summarise(
    df,
    across(where(is.numeric), sum),
    across(where(is.character), ~'Total')
  )
)
```

which works.

In both cases, `df` is passed as the first arg to `bind_rows()`. In the second example, it’s also passed to `summarise()` due to the `.`.

Comment: A beautiful answer. It addresses the crust of the problem. Thanks heaps.